# Tastypie ImportError: cannot import name get_via_uri

Tags: django, tastypie

This might be a duplicate, but I am unable to find the exact answer.

I am trying to retrieve an object from the resource_uri in django-tastypie

In my api.py I do

```
from tastypie.resources import get_via_uri
```

but it gives me the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name get_via_uri
```

Any quick suggestions ? Or should I just copy paste the get_via_uri code ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_via_uri`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#Resource.get_via_uri) is a `Resource` method. You'll need to call it on a `resource` instance.

Comment: so you mean I don't need to import it ? and if my resource is called ObjectResource, and I am inside the resource definition, I can just use self.get_resource_uri() ?

Comment: @user3580099 Correct. You can see this being done in the [Tastypie source](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/fd55aa323abc2933b18e017ed997e324468b9c1c/tastypie/resources.py#L1551) as well.